# ¿Como puede mantener un mantener un Switch Button ON en android studio?

Tags: android

Buen día gente, tengo el siguiente problema: tengo un switch button que al ponerlo en ON empieza a reproducir un archivo mp3, hasta ahi todo bien, el problema es que cuando cambio de pantalla (es decir cambio la orientacion) y vuelvo a regresar a la pantalla en la que tenia el switch button, éste aparece como OFF, mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de mantenerlo en ON cuando cambio de pantalla y regreso a la misma.

Este es mi código:

```
swtMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){

                mp.start();

                swtMusic.setSaveEnabled(true);
            }
            else{

                mp.stop();
                swtMusic.setChecked(false);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: puedes poner algo de código ?

Comment: Hola Juampi, te sugiero revisar [ask] para realizar tu pregunta correctamente, al menos puedes agregar lo que has realizado como comenta Diego. No olvides realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: @Juampi investiga sobre [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html?hl=es-419).

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo debes usar dos métodos en tu clase para salvar tus datos, obviamente no es la única forma pero es la que en lo personal he probado

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("estado", switch.isChecked());
}
```

y en segundo metodo

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    cont = savedInstanceState.getBool("estado");
    switch.setChecked(cont);
}
```

Comment: Hay que esperar a que el OP realice de una mejor forma su pregunta. Lo que agregas salva una variable, pero que sucede si cambias de pantalla o si la Activity se destruye, esto ya no funcionaría.

Answer (score 0):

la pregunta del compañero es sencilla:

> hay alguna forma de mantenerlo en ON cuando cambio de pantalla y
>   regreso a la misma.

Te confirmo, si hay varias formas de mantener el botón en ON cuando cambias de actividad o cuando la actividad por una rotación se vuelve a recrear.

Ahora como la pregunta esta muy abierta para poder brindar una solución concreta... Estoy seguro que muchas veces nos pasa a los desarrolladores que no sabemos como preguntar algo porque no sabemos como funcionan las cosas.

Te recomiendo echar un ojo a estos dos documentos sobre almacenamiento y ciclos de vida de una actividad. Los mismos te ayudarán a entender como funciona y porque pasa lo que describes en tu pregunta.

Sobre almacenamiento o persistencia de datos: este enlace te ayuda a saber que opciones hay disponibles para guardar datos incluso si la aplicación se cierra.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html?hl=es-419

Sobre ciclos de vida: este enlace te ayuda a comprender que las actividades tienen ciclos de vida y al lanzar una nueva actividad como es tu caso, la actividad desde donde lanzas cambia de estado, igualmente sucede si hay un cambio de rotación. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=es-419

Saca el tiempo de leer estos enlaces son muy útiles y te podrán guiar a la respuesta o bien al menos a formular mejor tu pregunta.

Saludos!

Comment: gracias por los enlaces, les echaré un vistazo, una disculpa si no supe formular mi pregunta concretamente